# How to display custom message in the Exit Confirmation Dialog, NOT the default browser message

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to show confirmation dialog if user leaves the page after make changes.
I have that code and it work fine but the problem is that the message in the confirmation dialog is not my custom message but it is default message that belong to the Browser and each Browser has its own message.

```
window.onbeforeunload = myFunction;
        function myFunction() {
            if (inputChanged)
                return "You do not save the changes";
        }
```

I wwant to display my own message in the confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The browser might do that, I guess they do it because the user might be deceived by some trickery in the prompt.

> Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with; some don't display them at all. For a list of specific browsers, see the Browser_compatibility section.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: I try that code before but not work:                                                       window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};

Comment: If you read through the page, you'll see that only IE supports custom text for the prompt message, all the other browsers intentionally substitute it with the default one.

Comment: Is that mean, there is no solution for that ?

Comment: Yeah, for the prompt at least, I guess you can make a div or something that shows the desired text